# Spring OAuth2 Provider Client Authentication 401 not authorized error using CloudFoundry as client

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry

This question is primarily for the CloudFoundry developers.  Has something changed that would make a client application using spring social unable to use basic client authentication to communicate with my core application hosting an oauth2 provider?  When I run the client application on a tomcat server everything works.  It also worked on a cloudfoundry microinstance about 2 weeks ago.  Now I get a 401 unauthorized error making a call to the service at "../oath/token" on my core application.  To see what I am referring to, my application is http://www.metroseattlegamers.com  If you click the "Games" link at the top it brings you to a separate application.  If you sign in using the application at http://gamerepository.metroseattlegamers.com, the "sign in with metroseattlegamers account" button uses custom spring social code to communicate to my spring oauth2 provider code at http://www.metroseattlegamers.com.  That all works fine because it is running on two separate tomcat servers on different machines.  However, I tested and wrote everything using cloudfoundry micro instances to run client apps.  As I said, it was working about a week or two weeks ago.  Now I get a 401 error when I run the client on a cloudfoundry instance.  Everything still works great when I run two separate tomcat servers on separate machines.  Rather than include a bunch of code, I am just curious if anything has changed with how cloudfoundry microinstances work in the last week or two that may have caused this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No as far as I know. Would it be possible for you to file a ticket at the official support page: http://support.cloudfoundry.com. There you can get a private agent to assist and maybe share the implementation of your app to further debug. You will need to sign in by the account you registered on www.cloudfoundry.com.

Comment: You are right.  Nothing changed.  Somehow I missed an environment variable pointing to my production environment while I was testing.  It was one of those things where I had been working on the problem too long and could not see the obvious.